# Performing automated operation in a specific date

Tags: database, postgresql

Here's my environment: my db holds some data related to elections.
Each election has a start time and an end time, in this period people can vote for someone.

I'd like to make so that, when the end time occurs, the db makes a vote count and automatically set a winner field on a table based on the user who got the most of votes.
This event has to be added to each new row inserted in the "elections" table, each row will have a different end time, obviously.

Is it possible to create a trigger who awakens when a datetime is reached?

Comment: You can check [pgAgent](http://www.pgadmin.org/download/pgagent.php).

Comment: I'd like to do it by code

Comment: The answer to your question "Is it possible to create a trigger who awakens when a datetime is reached" is "no". You must use an external process to trigger an action.

Answer (score 1):

You can only do something like this using `cron`, [`pgAgent`](http://www.pgadmin.org/download/pgagent.php) or similar job scheduler.

But you don't have to do it this way. Just use a table like:

```
create table election_candidates (
  election_id int not null references elections(election_id),
  user_id int not null references users(user_id),
  votes int not null default 0
);
create index election_candidates_election_id_votes_idx
  on election_candidates(election_id, votes);
```

When election is started you create `election_candidates` row for every candidate with `votes=0`. When you receive a vote you just use `update election_candidates set votes=votes+1 where election_id=? and user_id=?`. If you need to record votes than do it in another table and update this table using a trigger.

When you need to check a winner you just use:

```
with max_votes as (
  select election_id, max(votes) as max_vote from election_candidates
    where election_id=?
    group by election_id
)
select user_id from election_candidates
  natural inner join max_votes
  where votes=max_vote;
```

But remember that there can be more than one winner when more than one candidate would receive the same number of votes.